# ¿Cómo evitar que todos los children de una tabla de antd se abran al darle click a uno solo. React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design

Estoy bloqueada con un problema que tengo en una tabla de antd que estoy usando.
Actualmente tengo un endpoint que me trae las columnas y los datos, así mismo una propiedad llamada 'children' la cual le permite a la tabla tener hijos que se despliegan al darle click al ícono: [aquí la imagen de lo que quiero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6xhs.png). Desafortunadamente actualmente lo que pasa es que al dar click en un icono de  uno de los children, se abren todos. Como lo puedo solucionar?? Aquí dejo mi código de react
Así consumo mi endpoint.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `JWT ${fuenteActual.token_django}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      // Agregamos la columna "children" con los datos de los hijos al arreglo de resultados
      const dataWithChildren = response.data.results.map((record) => {
        return {
          ...record,
          children: record.datex_archivo_children.map((child) => {
            return {
              key: child.id,
              name: child.nombre,
              descripcion: child.descripcion,
              nombre_descriptivo: child.nombre_descriptivo,
            };
          }),
        };
      });

      setData(dataWithChildren);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, "error");
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
 };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);


y el return así. 
 <Table
          dataSource={data}
          columns={columns}
          expandable={{ expandedRowRender }}
        />
```

Estuve probando con la propiedad Expandable pero no lo he logrado, no funciona.

Comment: Si abris el ejemplo que te da la documentacion en codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/3x52ju), tu error se puede apreciar si le pones a todos los key el mismo valor. Creo que por ahi viene la mano, sera que tus ``child.id`` son todos repetidos? Capaz podes hacer ``.map((child, index) => ...`` y en lugar de ``child.id`` pasarle ``index`` al key?

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos la data que devuelve tu datex_archivo_children y tu esponse.data.results ? Creeria que tambien seria bueno ver el codigo de tu table o si estas usando componentes de terceros ver cuales para ver la docu de lo que necesita para que funcione bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente era porque recibía el mismo key por defecto desde el back.